# Workflow rule creation process

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have to create a workflow so that it shows a message when a sample lot Expiration date is just 90Days ahead. Can some one show me the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a formula field instead, displaying a certain text/image when the expiration date is getting too close. Something like:

```
IF(  
TODAY() > Expiration_date__c - 90,  
"Warning Message",  
"")
```

Instead of using text, you could use like a green check or red cross image to make it visually more appealing.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you solve your question, feel free to vote it up.

Comment: Robin   I am new here. please let me know how to vote?

Comment: Just clicking the arrow up sign next to the answer votes it up. You can also mark it as accepted if it solved your question by clicking the green check.

Comment: Cant vote Robin Reputation low here. :(

Answer (score 0):

This will help.https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wf.htm&language=en_US
You can create the work flow rule on the object containing sample lot Expiration date field.
Add Time-Dependent Workflow 90 days before sample lot Expiration date and add one  Time-Dependent Workflow action as email alert.Create your email template and add the template in this email alert.Dont forget to Activate the workflow rule after creation.

Comment: Yes I have done that but don't know why not receiving mails.